# GET data from HTML and process in python using Flask and POST back in same HTML

Tags: html, python-3.x, flask

hi i am trying to implement a chat type module. My front end in a HTML page from which i GET a data. The obtained data is passed to python flask. And finally the processed data must be posted back to the same HTML page.

I am able to GET the data. But unable to post it back to the same HTML page.

the following is the HTML code

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
function ajaxcall(){
var p_name = $('#p_name').val();
var p_email = $('#p_email').val();

  $.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/getdata?chatbox="+p_name);
  }
</script>
</head>
<form action="" method="POST" name='chat'>
    <div>
    {{text_typed}}
    </div>
    Enter Chat: <textarea id="p_name" name="chatbox" rows="4" cols="50"></textarea>
    <input type="button" onclick="ajaxcall()" value="submit me!" />
    <label name='get_test' id='get_test'></label>
</form>
</html>
```

the value entered in the text area must be posted in {{text_typed}}. i am unable to get this

this is my python flask coding [i am performing this in a local environment]

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request, render_template, flash, url_for, redirect #import objects from the Flask model
app = Flask(__name__) #define app using Flask

@app.route('/')
def hello():
    print("hello")
    return "Welcome to mychat.in"

@app.route('/chat', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def chat():
    return render_template("getpost.html")

@app.route('/getdata', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def getdata():
    print('hi')
    text_typed = request.args.get('chatbox')
    print(text_typed)        
    return render_template("getpost.html", text_typed = text_typed)# this is the line i am trying to post back in html

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your JS code:

```
$.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/getdata?chatbox="+p_name);
```

According to the [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) you should put it as

```
$.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/getdata?chatbox="+p_name, null, function(data) {
Put your code to insert returned _data_ into the form here. 
});
```