# Javascript to python data is not sent i am using flask and unable to convert

Tags: javascript, python, html, flask

(comment how can i improve way to present the question as well)
I am making a project for typing speed web application using Flask. But the problem is in calculating the time it takes for user to type. I've **tried to calc time using page response time** using @app.before_request and after... but it didn't showed time.
So i applied JS(javascript) function to calculate time(hidden input from js[embeded] to html) and return to my python code along with the input data and calculated the time difference.
BUT there a value error
*File "c:----\Desktop\Flask\main.py", line 32, in typefast
in typefast
time_taken = end_time - float(start_time)
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'start_time'*

The functional code is as follow:

```
{%block basic%}
<form method = 'Post' action = '/result'>
    <label for="text">Type the text below:</label><br>
    <textarea name="text" rows="10" cols="50">monster Speed</textarea>
    <input type="hidden" name="start_time" value="" id="start_time">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
{% endblock %}

{%block scripts%}
    <script>
        // curr time
        
**var start_time = String(new Date().getTime());
document.getElementById("start_time").value = start_time;**
    
    </script>
    {%endblock%}
```

```
@app.route('/result',methods = ['Get','Post'])
def typefast() -> 'html': 
    # request.parameter_storage_class = ImmutableOrderedMultiDict
    form_dta = request.form['start_time']
    #start_time = next(form_dta)
    start_time = start_time.strip('\'')
    
    end_time = time.time()
    text = request.form['text']
    time_taken = end_time - float(start_time)
    words_typed = len(text.split())
    typing_speed = words_typed / (time_taken/60)
    return render_template('results.html',  the_title='It\'s Good to see your work!', typing_speed=form_dta)
```

The value of start time as concluded by python is > symbol.
I've tried to strip the string** but didn't worked either. Other methods suggestions are also accepted for calculating time taken from input to submit. Also referred to related questions like [html to flask method =Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42788628/get-data-from-html-and-process-in-python-using-flask-and-post-back-in-same-html) but didn't got the desired output.
Also i tried json format but couldn't get it right either.
Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with that the js code is not included in the main code.
The correcct procedure should be:

```
{%block basic%}
<form method = 'Post' action = '/result'>
        <label for="text">Type the text below:</label><br>
        <textarea name="text" rows="10" cols="50">monster Speed</textarea>
        <input type="hidden" name="start_time" value="" id="start_time">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
<script>
            // curr time
            
    **var start_time = String(new Date().getTime());
    document.getElementById("start_time").value = start_time;**
        
</script>
{% endblock %}
```